# Excel working time calculation

Tags: excel

I am trying to put together an excel spreadsheet to track working time. A standard working day is say 8 hours with one hour lunch, say 40 hours total, 35 hours working. I need to track over and under time on a given day, and total this for a week period. The reason is to that if someone only takes a 30 minute lunch for three days, they can then take 1.5 hours off early at the end of the week for example.

Example daily record:

```
Mon - 9-6, 1 hour lunch = 8 working hours, 1 hour lunch, balance = 0 (the perfect day)
Tue - 8-6, 1 hour lunch = 9 working hours, 1 hour lunch, balance = +60 (one hour over)
Wed - 9-4, 1 hour lunch = 7 working hours, 1 hour lunch, balance = -60 (one hour under)
Thu - 9-6, 30 min lunch = 8 working hours, 30 min lunch, balance = +30 (30 mins over)
Fri - 9-6, 30 min lunch = 8 working hours, 30 min lunch, balance = +30 (30 mins over)
```

Example end of week totals

I am recording start/end/lunch times in excel in custom "time format" cells: 09:00 - 17:00
I am getting the hours with this formula: =TEXT(End-Start,"hh:mm")
I enter the lunch time in "time format" 00:30 (30 mins)
I get the actual time worked  with this formula: =TEXT(Total-Lunch,"hh:mm")

When I try to add together / sum the values however I am not getting anything...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please can you provide some sample data showing how you have the dates, start time, lunch, end time etc. set out. Also, this question may be better suited to the SuperUser site unless you are specifically after a programming solution (i.e. VBA).

Comment: Don't use TEXT function - as the name implies it returns a text result and when you sum text you get zero - just use `=End-Start` and use cell formatting to display in required format, same for `=Total-Lunch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with six columns

```
Date  / Start   / Lunch    / Lunch   / Stop    / total
3-sep / 8:29 AM / 12:30 PM / 1:30 PM / 5:44 PM / 8.25
```

For total, I calculate with the function `=MROUND((D5-C5+F5-E5)*24,0.25)`. This rounds the total to the closest 0.25 hour (that is, 15 min).

Just for kicks, I accumulate the excess hours. Excel will put in the current time by pressing Ctrl+Shift ; (semicolon).